# how to add same prefix to every smarty template

Tags: smarty

Every time a tpl file is included the system first looks for a site-specific version of the file and falls back to a standard one if the site specific one does not exist. So perahps I put include "customer/main/test1.tpl". If our site is google, the system would first look for "customer/main/google_test1.tpl" and fall back to "customer/main/test1.tpl" if that file doesn't exist.

Note: Smarty 2.6.x

Comment: You didn't ask anything here. Please examplain what you are trying to do, what you have tried and what problems stop you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know about the built-in template directory cascade? [addTemplateDir](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.template.dir.tpl) and [setTemplateDir](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl) allow you to specify multiple directories:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir(array(
  'google' => 'my-templates/google/',
  'default' => 'my-templates/default/',
));

$smarty->display('foobar.tpl');
```

Smarty will first try to find `my-templates/google/foobar.tpl`, if not found try `my-templates/default/foobar.tpl`. Using this, you can build a complete templating cascade.

---

That won't be too helpful if you have lots of elements on the same cascade-level. Say you had specific templates for google, yahoo and bing besides your default.tpl. A solution could involve the [default template handler function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.default.template.handler.func.tpl). Whenever Smarty comes across a template it can't find, this callback is executed as a measure of last resort. It allows you to specify a template file (or template resource) to use as a fallback.

So you could {include}, {extend}, ->fetch(), ->display() `site_google.tpl`. If the file exists, everything is fine. If it doesn't, your callback could replace `_google` with `_default` to fallback to the default template.

---

If neither template_dir cascade nor default template handler function seems applicable, you'll want to dig into [custom template resources](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.custom.tpl).

Comment: I have very old  smarty version file (version 2.6.9) which does not support addTemplateDir and setTemplateDir is there any other way? Can i change core functionality to adding the prefix.

Comment: Smarty 2.6.9? can you at least upgrade to Smarty 2.6.26? I'm not sure how I would have done it way back when. But of course you can modify internals. If I remember right, Smarty2 already had some options for custom resource handlers and default template handler function: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/template.resources.tpl

Comment: I try to install current latest version of smarty in x-cart which producing following error.
Undefined property: Templater::$webmaster_mode in  Smarty-3.1.8/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 667, i will be really appreciated for  help 

Templater::$webmaster_mode is a X-cart class prperty it was working fine with older version of smarty when I changed the version now  it is created problem

Comment: Thank you very much rodneyrehm